# Expect : error can't read "ip": no such variable

Tags: tcl, expect

I am a newbie in expect / TCL and trying to parse an HTML page that has output some thing like below:

```
<li><p>Timestamp: Wed, 14 Nov 2012 16:37:50 -0800
<li><p>Your IP address: 202.76.243.10</p></li>
<li><p class="XXX_no_wrap_overflow_hidden">Requested URL: /</p></li>
<li><p>Error reference number: 1003</p></li>
<li><p>Server ID: FL_23F7</p></li>
<li><p>Process ID: PID_1352939870.809-1-428432242</p></li>
<li><p>User-Agent: </p></li>
```

My script is below. I am able to get the web page which I am not able to parse the line "Your IP address:" which is giving me errors:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout -1
spawn telnet www.whatismyip.com 80
send "GET /\r\n"
expect
set output $expect_out(buffer)
foreach line [split $output \n] {
        regexp {.*<li><p>Your IP Address Is:.*?(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)} $line ip
        if {[string length ${ip}]} {
                puts $ip
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
    Connection closed by foreign host.
can't read "ip": no such variable
    while executing
"string length ${ip}"
    ("foreach" body line 3)
    invoked from within
"foreach line [split $output \n] {
        regexp {.*<li><p>Your IP Address Is:.*?(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)} $line ip
        if {[string length ${ip}]} {
 ..."
    (file "./t4" line 7)
```

Any pointers where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression did not match, so the variable was not assigned. You should check the result of `regexp` to see if the match succeeded; when not using the `-all` option to `regexp`, you can treat it like a boolean. Try this:

```
foreach line [split $output \n] {
    if {[regexp {<li><p>Your IP Address Is:.*?(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(?!\d)} $line -> ip]} {
        puts $ip
    }
}
```

The `->` is really a (weird!) variable name which will hold the whole matched string; we're not interested in it (just the parenthetical part) so we use the non-alphabetic to mnemonically say “this is going to there” (the submatch to the `ip` variable).

Comment: Thanks it works but the IP value is getting truncated only by its last character value. My code is  if {[regexp {<li><p>Your IP address:.*?(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)} $line -> ip]} { and if The markup is <li><p>Your IP address: 202.76.243.10</p></li> I get puts $ip as 202.76.243.1 - the 0 in the end is being left out

Comment: Ah! You've been bitten by non-greediness. For really rather nasty technical reasons, _all_ the quantifiers in that RE are being non-greedy: you need to ensure that the RE is appropriately anchored, which is done by putting in a negative lookahead (`(?!\d)`: “there isn't a digit next”) at the end of the RE.

Comment: The “really rather nasty technical reasons” have to do with Tcl's use of an automata-theoretic RE engine instead of the stack-based system of PCRE and related. The code that works this out is definitely non-trivial and scary-complicated. Myself, I try to always write entirely greedy REs; that's how I was taught, long ago, and their behavior is (relatively) easy to understand.

Comment: The original RE was one you supplied, but with the leading `.*` lopped off as you didn't really need it, but which forced the rest of the RE to be interpreted as greedy… and which I didn't spot. Oh well!

Comment: By the way, try just to use the http package: `package require http; set tok [http::geturl www.whatismyip.com]; if {[regexp {<li><p>Your IP Address Is:.*?(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(?!\d)} [http::data $tok] -> ip]} {puts $ip}; http::cleanup $tok`

Answer (score 1):

Your line contains "address" (lowercase) but you're trying to match "Address" (uppercase). Add the
`-nocase` option to the regexp command. Also, Tcl regular expressions cannot have mixed greediness -- the first quantifier determines if the whole expression is greedy or non-greedy (I can't find where this is documented right now).

```
regexp -nocase {IP Address.*(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})} $line -> ip
```

Comment: Same value I get here - as mentioned that the ip value is getting truncated by last character - if markup value is IP address: 202.76.243.10</p></li> I get 'puts $ip' as 202.76.243.1 - the 0 in the end is being left out

Answer (score 0):

If your ultimate goal is to get your host's external IP, then go with an API solution, such as one from exip.org:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

set api http://api-nyc01.exip.org/?call=ip
if {[catch {exec curl --silent $api} output]} {
    puts "Failed to acquire external IP"
} else {
    puts "My external IP is $output"
}
```

Please visit their [API](http://www.exip.org/api) site for more information, especially if you live outside the USA. This solution requires `curl`, which you might need to install.